# Using enum parameter in functions

Tags: c++, enumeration

I'm working on Windows, in C++ with Visual Studio.

I have a class that has a:

```
enum algorithmStatus { LOADING, DETECTION, TRACKING, LOST };
```

In the declaration I want to use a setter and getter to change the status, something like:

```
void MyStatusClass::setAlgorithmStatus(algorithmStatus newStatus)
{
    //_Status = newStatus;
    //_Status = MyStatusClass::algorithmStatus::LOADING;
}
```

But I can't compile because I get:

> Error  5   error C2511: 'void MyStatusClass::setAlgorithmStatus(MyStatusClass::algorithmStatus)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Nft_Status'    c:\MyStatusClass.cpp    197

How can I do that setter correctly?

**EDIT:**

In header is already declarated:

```
    void setAlgorithmStatus(MyStatusClass::algorithmStatus newStatus);
```

and:

```
void setAlgorithmStatus(algorithmStatus newStatus);
```

In cpp the function is declared just i write on top.

**SOLVED**

The problem was i used a MyStatusClass::algorithmStatus in the constructor, you don´t need to use the MyStatusClass::, and its advisable don´t use it if you don´t need it.

Comment: Post the definition of the class.

Comment: There is something wrong in your class declaration. Probably you didn't declare `setAlgorithmStatus` in your class. Or you declared that function in a wrong way. The function declaration should look something like this - `void setAlgorithmStatus(MyStatusClass::algorithmStatus my_variable);`

Comment: The Signature of your function might me different in declaration and definition

Comment: Please note that `_S` is a prefixed reserved to the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for **[error code C2511](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20fs9x81.aspx)** gives you a good list to lookout for:

> `identifier` : overloaded member function not found in `class`
>
> No version of the function is declared with the specified parameters. Possible causes:
>
> 1. Wrong parameters passed to function.
> 2. Parameters passed in wrong order.
> 3. Incorrect spelling of parameter names.

**Always, lookup the error codes to get help in resolving compilation errors.**

Comment: I already checked this. Visual studio detect the enum. The name its ok, in correct order.

Comment: @Piperoman: Have you declared the function correctly in your class `MyStatusClass`?

Comment: I think its ok, i do it on header like: void setAlgorithmStatus(MyStatusClass::algorithmStatus newStatus);

Comment: and like void setAlgorithmStatus(algorithmStatus newStatus);

Comment: @Piperoman: You need to declare the function inside the class in header file and you need to include that header file in the cpp file which uses/calls the function. The function will be defined in cpp file where you define the class, Why are you declaring the function again in cpp file where it is called?

Comment: The class is working fine to normal functions, but this one, when i use the enum parameter to set the data, i get the problem. I don´t know why is not detecting the declaration correctly. If i use a int parameter, work fine.